# Simple.OData.Client error: The property 'Context' does not exist on type

Tags: c#, odata, blazor

I have a problem trying to pass a model through the "set" parameter of my odata call.

> Simple.OData.Client error: The property 'Context' does not exist on type. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.

The model that I am passing is called "Rule" and the call accepts the said parameter through the body. Does anybody know what is it due to?

Comment: Little code of model and controller would help.